# NOOBS installed, but not booting properly with Kernel Panic Error Code 0x00000004"

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, kernel, boot

I downloaded latest NOOBS v1.9.2 from raspberry site.

Installed it on RaspberryPi 2 Box.

It installed successfully.

I did integrate some files in NOOBS and did re-build it. (re-created NOOBS)

The newly created NOOBS works on Raspberry 2 and Raspberry 3, but it does not work with Raspberry 1.

It is successfully installed on RaspberryPi 1 but while booting it provides below error.

```
Kernel panic - not syncing : Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: Init Not tainted 4.4.11+ #888
```

I have tried below :

(1) update kernel and firmware using command:

```
"rpi-update" command.
```

(2) update broken packages using command :

```
"apt-get -f install"
```

(3) get latest update command :

```
"apt-get update'
```

(4) Re-installed boot loader using below command

```
Command : sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader
```

This problem looks like, the kernel is not able to compile some files to machine level code.

I have also attached the image of the occured error :[image]

Comment: What do you mean specifically when you say "I did integrate some files in NOOBS and did re-build it. (re-created NOOBS)" ?

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson Actually we have one webui application, which we integrate in NOOBS. After adding this application source to NOOBS, I did rebuild NOOBS on CentOS and created modified NOOBS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem as below :

- Install original NOOBS on RaspberryPi 1 instead of Raspberry Pi 2 or 3.
- Now change its settings according to requirement.
- Build it and re-create the NOOBS.
- Now check the installation of re-created NOOBS on RPI1, 2 and 3. it will work on all 3.

Actually, from this I understood that the environment of RPI1 is compatible with RPI2 and RPI3.